# Variable values in Oracle where Clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to pass an variable value in my Select statement where clause

```
Declare v_WK varchar(20);
exec :v_WK :='Wk 6'

Select * from myTable Where Column = :v_Wk
```

**In toad it pop up the filtering window(How do I avoid that)**

DATE_DIM table is like below

```
UNIQUE_ID   WEEK_NAME   WEEK_BEGIN  WEEK_END
1   Week 6, 2018    20180205    20180211
2   Week 5, 2018    20180129    20180204
3   Week 4, 2018    20180122    20180128
4   Week 3, 2018    20180115    20180121
```

And Fact Table is like

```
ACCT_ID WEEK_NAME   SALES
10001   20180205    10
10001   20180206    20
10001   20180207    10
10001   20180208    15
1002    20180129    100
1002    20180130    100
1002    20180131    100
1002    20180132    100
```

Here I need an Output like

```
ACCT_ID WEEK_NAME   SALES
10001   Week 6, 2018    55
1002    Week 5, 2018    406
```

So Basically I wanna loop each ACCT_ID like

```
SELECT *
FROM Fact_Table
where Week_Name between (Select Week_Begin from DATE_DIM WHERE WEEk_NAME =: v_Wknm) /* Here I will have to loop Each Week_name for Each Acct_ID */
```

This is what I have tried

```
DECLARE v_Init_Cnt NUMBER(10):=1;
        v_Tot_Cnt NUMBER(10);

BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_Tot_Cnt FROM DIM_DATE;

    WHILE(v_Init_Cnt <= v_Tot_Cnt)
    LOOP

    dbms_output.put_line(v_Init_Cnt);

    VARIABLE v_Id NUMBER(10);
    exec :v_Id:= v_Init_Cnt;

    dbms_output.put_line('var' || v_Id);

    SELECT * FROM FACT_TABLE 
    WHERE WEEK_NAME between (select WEEk_BEGIN FROM DIM_DATE WHERE UNIQUE_ID :=v_Init_Cnt) and (select WEEk_END FROM DIM_DATE WHERE UNIQUE_ID :=v_Init_Cnt) 

    v_Init_Cnt :=  v_Init_Cnt +1;
    END LOOP;

END;
```

I am not bit handy in PL/SQL like in MSSQL, sorry if this is simple question

Comment: how about set define off; ??

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `VARIABLE` command to define bind variables. Also note that you should use `VARCHAR2`. In Toad, you may have to do "Execute as script" or run as`sqlplus` for this to work.

```
VARIABLE v_WK VARCHAR2(20)
exec :v_WK :='Wk 6'

Select * from myTable Where Column_name = :v_Wk;
```

Regarding your code block, we don't use a `TABLE` variable in Oracle as in TSQL. Also, you can't run the above select statement and blocks in PL/SQL scope( i.e within `BEGIN..END` ). It would be better if you tell us what you are  ultimately trying to accomplish, so that an efficient solution could be provided.

**EDIT** : You don't need plsql to get your output. Use a simple join query like this.

```
SELECT a.acct_id,
       b.week_name,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   fact a
       JOIN date_dim b
         ON a.week_name BETWEEN b.week_begin AND b.week_end
GROUP  BY a.acct_id,
          b.week_name;
```

Comment: Hi @kaushik, I have update my questions accordingly. Really appreciate your effort.!!

Comment: @Tpk43 : Take a look at the edits. You don't need loops to get this desired output.